# Using sklearn Linear Regression and PCA in a single Pipeline

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a Pandas data frame with 20 numeric features and a numeric response column. I would like to first apply PCA to bring the dimensionality down to 10 and then run Linear Regression to predict the numeric response. I can do this currently using two steps

```
pipeline = Pipeline([('scaling', StandardScaler()),
                     ('pca', PCA(n_components=20, whiten=True))])
newDF = pipeline.fit_transform(numericDF)

Y = df["Response"]
model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(newDF, Y)
```

Is there a way to combine Linear Regression in the above pipeline? I ask this question because

1. `fit_transform` is not supported in Linear Regression.
2. `fit_predict` can't be used with PCA.
3. It's not a one-off use case

How could I run PCA and then Linear Regression all in the same pipeline?

Comment: any hope of considering my answer :) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The order of the pipeline steps matters.
The last step might implement `predict()`, while all the previous must have `fit_transform()`.
Also logically, you first transform your features and then apply a predictive classification/regression model

```
Y = df["Response"]
X=...
pipeline = Pipeline([('scaling', StandardScaler()),
                     ('pca', PCA(n_components=20, whiten=True)),
                      ('regr',LinearRegression())])
newDF = pipeline.fit_predict(numericDF)
```